# Selenium Chrome driver crashes when minimize the chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am making a bot that should help me find a rental house which is very hard at this moment. The goal of the bot is to automate the proces of checken for new apartments on the website that i am scraping.

Im doing a while loop that checks if there are any changes in a list of scraped elements.
Then the page should refresh it self until the scraped list of elements has changed (More, less or other elements in the list). If it changes it should shoot alert a message etc.

The problem right now is that when i minimize/close the chrome driver or click on VS code it crashes and empties the list.  There are no errors in the log because the code thinks that the list is empty while the page is not empty ..

Thanks for your help! The full code is below

```
def create_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    service = Service(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    return driver


def login(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'txtEmail').send_keys('XXXXXXXX@gmail.com')
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'txtWachtwoord').send_keys('XXXXXXXXX')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept"]'))).click()
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-secondary').click()


def search_page(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/zoekopdracht/']").click()


def list_of_woningen(driver):
    woningen = []
    woningLijst = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "stretched-link")

    for x in woningLijst:
        woningen.append(x.text)

    return woningen


def check_for_changes(driver, old_list):
    print("Checking for changes")
    new_list = list_of_woningen(driver)
    if old_list == new_list:
        print("No changes found")
        return False
    else:
        print("Changes found")
        print("Old list: ", old_list)
        print("New list: ", new_list)
        return True


def start_session(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    login(driver)
    search_page(driver)
    old_list = list_of_woningen(driver)
    
    while not check_for_changes(driver, old_list):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        #time.sleep(5)  # 30 seconds
        # a better approach for this, is to make a wait thread, if there are other functionalities for tha program
        driver.refresh()
    else:
        
        print("ALERT!!!")

    # return driver.page_source
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_session(create_driver(), 'https://hurenbij.vesteda.com/')
```

```
No changes found
Checking for changes
No changes found
Checking for changes
No changes found
Checking for changes
No changes found
Checking for changes
Changes found
Old list:  ['Bankierbaan 140', 'Boekbinderstraat 3', 'Rozemarijntuin 87', 'Parkzicht 78', 'Brinklaan 138B 1', 'Wijde Wormer 222', 'Sjees 16', 'Fideliolaan 258D', 'Kapittelweg 428', 'Haendelplein 107', 'Haendelplein 55', 'Bankierbaan 234', 'Parkzicht 35', 'Rozemarijntuin 85', 'Rozemarijntuin 101', 'Maan Bastion 170', 'Slachthuisstraat 165', 'Parkzicht 94', 'Slachthuisstraat 145', 'Reimsstraat 9', 'Sir Winston Churchillln 755', 'Sir Winston Churchillln 509']
New list:  ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
ALERT!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Following chromedriver options did the trick! Only adding headless didn't work. You should always add a window-size for it to work. Disable-gpu is added because a timeout error appears after a while. Hope i can help others with this solution!

```
options.add_argument("--headless") 
options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```